# QlikView "Copy Down" Previous NonZero Values

Tags: qlikview

I have a QlikView application of Employees, months and salaries (along with other stuff, obviously). I have also a column that tells me the percentage pay movement this month.

I'd like to, in the Load Script, "copy down" this data so that I can find the most recent previous pay percentage increase and the month (please see the picture).

So I effectively have the yellow data, and want to generate the red data, for each employee ID. I'm not massively fussed on EXACTLY what the non-zero values are - i.e. if they're zero or NULL or anything.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgCqT.png

Edit: Should probably note, this isn't my Excel/CSV file, this is the actual QlikView table - due to the way our data comes out of the source system, we have to calculate basic pay movements in the load script (along with other stuff) using 3 or 4 temporary tables, then load them all together.

Comment: have you tried using peek() ?

Comment: How would I use that?

Comment: above might be more useful actually

Answer (score 0):

in your read statement the lines for your 2 red columns should be something like.

```
If(PayIncreasePerc=0,Above(MostRecentPayInc,1),PayIncreasePerc) as MostRecentPayInc

If(PayIncreasePerc=0,Above(MostRecMonth,1),Month) as MostRecentPayIncMonth
```

if the pay increase is 0 then the most recent % and month is the same value as the previous row.
not sure what this will return for the 1st row. hopefully a null.